# Save user url request (get & post) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.2, devise

I have devise authentication, he save ip and user count, but I need to save url's address, what current user see (get and post request).

```
Example: http://example/example?search....
```

How I save this example and others url's pages when user surfing on site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Rails 3.2 or Rails 4 you can use `request.original_url` to get the current URL.

In your `application_controller.rb`:

```
before_filter :save_url

  def save_url
    # here you should save request.original_url
  end
```

You can specify actions's names in before_filter:

```
 before_filter :save_url, :only => :index
```

If you render some view from more actions, not just `index`, add them:

```
before_filter :save_url, :only => [:index,:name]
```

Comment: I know it, but how i save request.original_url every time when user do his request.

Comment: You can save it in `before_filter` at `application_controller`

Comment: Can you give more informations or links, how save it in before_filter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.url` in the action of your controller to determine the requested URL.

Further to know, whether a request is of type `GET` or `POST` , you can use these two methods :

```
request.get?

 OR

request.post?
```

Comment: To get reques's type: simply use `request.method`